# SVN:How to change the owner of a working copy

Tags: svn

In my machine I'm using a svn copy with user id:user1. I would like to change "user1" to "user2".
Please let me know how to change the user for SVN

Comment: Why don't you checkout a fresh working copy? You can always clear SVN auth cache BTW, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.tour.initial.authn-cache-purge

Comment: I tried it. while checkout it didn't ask me to enter credentials. By default it took the existing user

Comment: what's your SVN server? Does it support single sign-on?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to force SVN to treat you as a different user with:

```
svn update --username user1 --password newpassword
```

If you want it to forget about the old username and password you can delete the `~/.subversion/auth` directory which will clear the authentication cache.

Comment: Asker says that "while checkout it didn't ask me to enter credentials" so it's not the case here, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

1)You can change the user with

- Subversion 1.6 and earlier:

  ```
    svn switch --relocate protocol://currentUser@server/path protocol://newUser@server/path
  ```
- Subversion 1.7 and later:

  ```
    svn relocate protocol://currentUser@server/path protocol://newUser@server/path
  ```

To find out what `protocol://currentUser@server/path` is, run

```
svn info
```

in your working copy.

2)You can use [svndumptool](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/):

> svnadmin dump path/to/my/repo > repo.dump
>
> svndumptool transform-revprop svn:author originalregexp newvalue
> repo.dump newrepo.dump

3)and most easy thing to do,ask your admin(who manages repo browser) to create fresh login for you.